# foreignkey method not being added to user objects

Tags: django, django-models

I am using the following models for my first django site. But I am currently having problems with how to access the wishes of a user.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='group_users')
    description = models.TextField()
    added = models.DateTimeField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Wish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='wish_user')
    bought = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bought_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='wish_buyer')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='wish_adder')
    cost = models.FloatField()
    added = models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def is_bought(self):
        return self.bought % 2 == 1
    def is_editable(self):
        return self.added >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

When I go to the django shell I get the following:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from wish.models import Wish, Group
>>> user1 = User.objects.filter(id=1)[0]
>>> user1.group_set.all()
[]
>>> user1.wish_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'wish_set'
>>>
```

Why doesn't the User object get the wish_set like it does get the group_set ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you renamed them to `wish_user`, `wish_buyer` and `wish_adder`. Whereas for the group you have `wish_set` implicity from the `owner` property and the explicit `group_users`.

The `related_name` parameter tells Django how to name the reverse relation. If it's not given it will be `<field name>_set`

Comment: Ah, that does make sense! Just for other people searching this, when I use `>>> user1.wish_user.all()` it does return what I expected. Thanks!